# Is Laravel's Mail::to() method trimming symbols after "+" symbol and before "@" symbol?

Tags: laravel, email

Email string `some.user+test@example.com`, when passed into `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::to()` method, sends the email to `some.user@example.com`.

Is this expected? Is there a way to prevent this? Tried using `urlencode()` and `rawurlencode()` on the string but this results in an `RFC 2822 compliance error`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is unrelated to Laravel at all but rather part of RFC 822 standard, described [here](http://www.jacobsen.no/anders/blog/archives/2002/08/24/email_addresses_with_a_are_valid.html).